# Trying to Compare a dictionary to a text file

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying out python for a simple web **scraper** that checks a website for names, puts them all in a dictionary with the link, then compares the names to a list I all ready have saved. The problem I am stuck on is trying to make a new dictionary with the names from the website that are not in the saved list.

```
together = dict(zip(names, links))
final_dict = {}


for k, v in together.items():
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
        file_lines = f.readlines()
        if k in file_lines:
            print('All ready have that name.')
            pass
        else:
            print(k, v)
            final_dict.update({k, v})
    f.close()
```

The saved file only has the `k` value of the `together` dictionary.

Comment: Is your indentation broken on `if k in file_lines`?

Comment: Only in the question, not on the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change

```
file_lines = f.readlines()
```

to

```
file_lines = f.read().splitlines()
```

The former one keeps the newline `\n` at the end of the line.

In addition `final_dict.update({k, v})` should probably be `final_dict.update({k: v})` and as others already pointed out, you may have an issue with your indentation.

Comment: I took your hint and came up with: `file_lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]` and fixed the `({k: v})` , Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm isn't very efficient. For *each* item in `together`, it reads the entire file. If you handle each line in the file as you encounter it, it's much faster:

```
together = dict(zip(names, links))

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line in together:
            del together[line]
```